# What number of "Unique Keys" can be created in a Table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As we know we can have only one Primary key in a table, so is there any way to know the maximum number of Unique keys in a table.I have read a post according to which no of Unique keys depend on number of clustered index.

Check this link
http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/152739/

Comment: You can pretty much have as many unique keys as you like - I don't think there's any real-world limitation on those .... any unique constraint creates an index on the table - and as far as I know, you can have 999 indexes (or maybe that limit has been lifted in more recent versions of SQL Server by now) on every single table. And in SQL Server, you cannot ever have more than **1** clustered index on a table .... so the *number* of clustered indexes is always 0 or 1 .....

Comment: @marc_s The question asks for the maximum unique keys IN a table, not maximum allowed. But, the link posted, discusses the theoretical maximum possible. Now, Im confused.

Comment: The theoretical limit will probably involve some higher math; maybe the number of partitions of _all_ the columns. The practical limit is not relevant, IMO.

Comment: Provided forum thread is not very informative, you should not be counting on it.

Comment: With most limit questions - if you find yourself asking what the limit is (and it's not some obvious low value like 1 or 2), you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If this SQL Server then  check this [Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing youself with `unique` constraints and `clustered` constraints.

- `Unique` key is a key by which you can easily tell which **exatcly** record you are dealing with.
- `Clustered` key is a key which handles the **physical** position of the record on the hard disk.

So you can have many unique constraints for your record, but only the one which will order the records on the disk. Please refer [the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) mentioned by @user3414693, if you are using the MS SQL server:

> Nonclustered indexes per table:
>   999 (Maximum sizes/numbers SQL Server (32-bit))
>   999 Maximum sizes/numbers SQL Server (64-bit)

You should note that here are **all** the indexes for the table, not only the unique ones.

Can't find specific information for the Oracle right now.

PS: Also you should note that having the primary key as **clustered** key can be a serious performance problem for the huge tables if you have a primary key a `uniqueidentifier`-type of column. Uniqueidentifier for real is a very-very big number, and it isn't being sorted like `IDENTITY` columns, so it is possible to face a situation during adding the new record when you have to move **physically** all the table data.